# Velocity.js fires off fadeOut but not fadeIn

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

I have the following code It should

```
if($(window).scrollTop()!=0){
        console.log('doout');
        $("#topbottom").velocity("fadeOut", { delay: 500, duration: 1500 });
    }else{
        console.log('doin');
        $("#topbottom").velocity("fadeIn", { delay: 500, duration: 1500 });
    }
}
```

It fires off the fadeOut on scroll however it won't fire off the fade in. It does write doin to the console when I get back to scroll zero...

A bit confused.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are executing your provided code when scroll happens.

To achieve the desired effect you need to stop or finish previous animations and only fire new one once, if you don't stop previous animation all new ones will be queued.

You need to determinate when scroll position changes from 0 to any other position and from any other position to 0.

```
var isOnTop = true;

$(window).scroll(function(){
  var isCurrentOnTop = $(window).scrollTop()===0;

  if(isOnTop == isCurrentOnTop) //scroll has changed but we only care when has changed from or to 0
    return;

  isOnTop = isCurrentOnTop;

  var effect = isOnTop? "fadeIn": "fadeOut";


  $("#topbottom").velocity("finish").velocity(effect, { delay: 500, duration: 1500 });


});
```

Please check [this working fiddle](https://output.jsbin.com/bopezo)